# building in docker using buildpack-deps, but dependencies don't seem to be installed?

Tags: docker, build

I'm trying to write a Dockerfile to build Kaldi (an open source speech recognition system) based on the "buildpack-deps:jessie-scm" image.  This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-scm
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python2.7 libtool python libtool-bin make
RUN mkdir /opt/kaldi
RUN git clone https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi.git /opt/kaldi --depth=1
RUN ln -s -f bash /bin/sh
WORKDIR /opt/kaldi
RUN cd tools/extras && ./check_dependencies.sh
RUN cd tools && ./install_portaudio.sh
RUN cd tools && make -j 4 && make clean
RUN cd src && ./configure --shared --use-cuda=no && make depend && make -j 4 && make -j 4 online onlinebin online2 && make clean
```

This fails at the "check_dependencies.sh" script, which is complaining that various base dependencies aren't installed (g++, zlib, automake, autoconf, patch, bzip2) ... but the description of the image that I'm basing this on (https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/587934fb063d770d0611e94b57c9dd7a38edf928/jessie/Dockerfile) suggests that all of these dependencies should be available in the base image.  Why is my build failing here?

I should note that I've attempted these build steps on a bare Debian Jessie system with the required dependencies installed and they were successful there, so I don't think it's a problem with the build scripts provided with Kaldi, but definitely a Docker-related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've misunderstood the different tags for the `buildpack-deps` image.  The tags `*-scm` don't add source control tools to the bundled build tools and libraries, they only apply the source control tools, and the build tools are then added on top of those tools.  So I should just be using `buildpack-deps:jessie` not `buildpack-deps:jessie-scm` (the latter of which is basically a bare Debian system with git etc installed but nothing else).